# JavaScript only appears as text in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to coding, and looking into learning JavaScript currently. I have very little experience with HTML and now JavaScript. I updated Firefox and wrote a simple line of code

```
var greeting = "Ahoy";
var greet = function (){;
console.log(greeting)
};
greet();
```

However, when I open in Firefox, I get all those lines in the browser as it is in my notepad. Why does nothing happen, I was under the impression it should just show the greeting.

I also tried to create a HTML file with JavaScript, and only the HTML shows and nothing happens with the JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>World</p>

<script>
console.log(5 + 6);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the browser it just outputs the "Hello" "World" and ignores the console.log command completely. Can anyone help, or enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Have you pressed your `F12` key lately?

Comment: What did you name the file?

Comment: Do you know what you are even doing? Read up: [Console.log() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Comment: As with your second example, you'll need to surround any javascript in your `html` documents with `<script>...</script>`. Once you add `<script>` before the beginning of the code in your first example and `</script>` after the end, you will find that the function `greet()` will run.

Comment: @Rounin — The question implies the first example is in a .js file.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does nothing happen, I was under the impression it should just show the greeting.

Because browsers don't execute standalone JavaScript programs.

> In the browser it just outputs the "Hello" "World" and ignores the console.log command completely

`console.log` logs to the *console*; it doesn't output into the HTML. You need to open your browser's Developer Tools to see the results.

If you want to modify the rendered page, then you should use [DOM methods](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML).

Answer (score 0):

The "console.log" portion will only print to the console on the debug tools. Press F12 or Ctrl + Shift + I to open the dev tools in most browsers. Then navigate to the console from there. 
Next, you're not pointing to the javascript source anywhere. Change it to something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="yourJSFile.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>World</p>

<script>
console.log(5 + 6);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Where "yourJSFile.js" is the path and name to the javascript file on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

In your browser inspect element, click on the console and you will see:

Ahoy

11

It currently is working as expected

I created a fiddle so you can see other options https://jsfiddle.net/gf0L85vo/

like `alert();` and `appendChild(t);`

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>F2</kbd> in tab Console, you can see the result. If you want to see the result in the page try this.

```
var b = 5 + 6;
document.write(b);
```